# Conditional Rendering of div in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I'm a newbie to ReactJS. I want to insert a condition in my code below so that when noPeopleText.length > 0, then only should the "no-people-row" div render, otherwise, I do not want this div rendering to the DOM if noPeopleText is an empty string or undefined.

What's the best way do add in a conditional for this?

```
const peopleMember = (props) => {
    const { people, noPeopleText, title } = props;
    const hasPeople = Boolean(people && people.length);
    const peopleGroup = _.groupBy(people, (person, i) =>
        Math.floor(i / 2)
    );

    return (
    <div>
        { hasPeople &&
            <SectionHeader
                title={title}
            />
        }
        { (hasPeople || noPeopleText) &&
        <div className="c-team-members">
            <div className="container">
                { hasPeople ? _.map(peopleMemberGroups, (members, i) => (
                    <div className="row" key={i}>
                        {members && members.map((member, j) => (
                                <TeamMember
                                    key={j}
                                    name={member.name}
                                />
                            ))
                        }
                    </div>
                )) : //If noPeopleText.length > 0, render div below
                    <div className="row no-people-row">
                        <div className="col-xs-12" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: noPeopleText}} />
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        }
    </div>

    );
};
```

Answer (score 5):

You already have conditional rendering in your code. For example:

```
{ hasPeople &&
    <SectionHeader title={title} />
}
```

This will only render the component `SectionHeader` if `hasPeople` evaluates to `true`. If `hasPeople` evaluates to `false` then the whole expression would evaluate to `false` regardless of the second part of the `&&`. Thus it is never executed (rendered).

So do you want something like this?

```
const peopleMember = (props) => {
    const { people, noPeopleText, title } = props;
    const hasPeople = Boolean(people && people.length);
    const peopleGroup = _.groupBy(people, (person, i) =>
        Math.floor(i / 2)
    );

    return (
    <div>
        { hasPeople &&
            <SectionHeader
                title={title}
            />
        }
        { (hasPeople || noPeopleText) &&
        <div className="c-team-members">
            <div className="container">
                { hasPeople ? _.map(peopleMemberGroups, (members, i) => (
                    <div className="row" key={i}>
                        {members && members.map((member, j) => (
                                <TeamMember
                                    key={j}
                                    name={member.name}
                                />
                            ))
                        }
                    </div>
                )) : (noPeopleText.length > 0) &&
                    <div className="row no-people-row">
                        <div className="col-xs-12" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: noPeopleText}} />
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        }
    </div>

    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use a nested ternary operator:

```jsx
{ hasPeople
    ? //mapping
    : noPeopleText.length > 0
        ? <div className="row no-people-row">
            <div className="col-xs-12" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: noPeopleText}} />
          </div>
        : null
}
```